# Java JNDI is not returning foreign security principal members of a group

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I have the following Java code which is able to get members of a AD group. However, when a member is from a different trust domain and thus a foreign security principal, the code does not get that member. I wonder if someone has any prior experience with that and could provide some advice. Thanks a lot in advance!

`import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NameNotFoundException;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;

public class GroupMembers
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> members = new ArrayList<String>();

        String ldapUsername = "cn=accountname,OU=Service Accounts,OU=JKL,DC=GHI,DC=DEF,DC=ABC,DC=COM";
        String ldapPassword = "password";
        String servername = "ldaps://GHI.DEF.ABC.COM";
        String searchbase = "DC=GHI,DC=DEF,DC=ABC,DC=COM";
        String searchfilter = "(&(objectCategory=group)(sAMAccountName=groupname))";

        Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldapUsername);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapPassword);
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, servername);

        LdapContext ctx;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
            NamingEnumeration<?> results = null;
            try {
                SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
                controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
                results = ctx.search(searchbase, searchfilter, controls);

                while (results.hasMore()) {
                    SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) results.next();
                    Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
                    Attribute attr = attributes.get("member");

                    for (int i=0;i<attr.size();i++) {
                        members.add((String) attr.get(i));
                    }
                }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                if (results != null) {
                    try {
                        results.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                }
                if (ctx != null) {
                    try {
                        ctx.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            // Loop through the memebers of the and print them out
            for (int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(members.get(i));
            }
        } catch (NamingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}`

Comment: How are you connecting to Microsoft Active Directory? (to a DC or Global Catalog or ???)

Comment: What is in your `members` collection? I would expect that you have a list of distinguished names, which would include foreign security principals. (the DN would end with `CN=Foreign Security Principals,DC=GHI,DC=DEF,DC=ABC,DC=COM`)

Comment: Is it perhaps a very large group? And are you only seeing 1000 or 1500 members? AD will only return 1000 or 1500 at a time (depending on the version of Windows Server), and you need to ask for the next batch. That's described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/ad/enumerating-groups-that-contain-many-members